# Send new account information when new account is create in WHM

Tags: email, configuration, whm, whmcs

How to configure WHM, to send New Account Information, when account is created?

I tried:

```
Server Configuration -> Tweak Settings -> Send passwords when creating a new account = On
```

But still not sending email notification.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not getting account creations notification due to Alert Priority configuration. Can you please check that through WHM >> Server Contacts >> Contact Manager and adjust it with your requirements

Also please check this : https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/Contact+Manager